# OpenSUSE Tumbleweed: The GUI fails to Start. Tumbleweed boots to CLI

Tags: linux, opensuse

I recently installed OpenSUSE Tumbleweed (KDE Plasma) and it worked fine for the first time. However, second time I start it, it stucked. The animated Tumbleweed logo appears and then it freezes to a CLI, asking me to log in.

I have seen other threads that are generally related to Graphics card. But in my case I am not using any Graphic card. In my notebook, there are Intel Graphics built in. I have run the system upgrade, nothing happened. And I tried `zypper in -f xorg-x11*` as was mentioned on Stack Exchange but the problem still persists.

Here is the **[`/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`](https://paste.ee/p/GINJz)**.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the log file line number 69 and 70 are the problems:

```
    [   211.520] (II) Unloading intel
[   211.520] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
```

You can run `sudo zypper in xf86-video-intel` command to fix this. Since you cannot see the desktop, so you can connect to the WiFi using `nmcli` from the same screen that you have posted.

Steps to do that:

Step 1: Log in CLI with root or your credentials. After that run `nmcli con up <mySSID> --ask` command.

Step 2: Enter the password and then you can see the connection status.

Step 3: Now, run the command `sudo zypper in xf86-video-intel`.

Ste 4: Reboot the PC by runnng `reboot now` or `sudo reboot now`.

Things should be fixed now and you will see the log in screen and GUI.